# AWS SFTP from AWS Transfer Family

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am planning to spin-up AWS Managed SFTP Server. AWS Documentation say, I can create upto 20 users. Can I configure for 20 users 20 different buckets and assign seperate previleges ? Is this a possible configuration ?

All I am looking for exposing same endpoint with different vendors having access to different AWS S3 buckets to upload their files to designated AWS S3 buckets.

Appreciate all your thoughts and response at the earliest.

Thanks

Comment: Would you consider giving them ways to upload to Amazon S3 _without_ using SFTP? It is much easier and simpler to go straight to S3 if you're willing to do that. How many vendors do you expect to have?

Comment: Hi John, to start with it is only 1 vendor but this list might start to grow as and when sources start pushing data into S3 based datalake in AWS. But what are the other simple ways to bring the data into s3 buckets ?

Comment: Simple ways are: Using a web page to upload (like adding attachments to an email); Using the AWS CLI to copy a file or even a whole directory to S3 (good with a script); using a drag & drop product like Cyberduck to let them drag their files across; mounting S3 as a virtual drive using products like Mountain Duck. None of them require anything on the server-side. The only question is how to vend access credentials. If there's just a small number of vendors, you could issue them with IAM User credentials with permission to access their own bucket, or only their directory in a shared bucket.

Comment: Where id you get the 20-user limit? I was unable to find anywhere that mentioned this. [AWS Transfer Family endpoints and quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/transfer-service.html) shows the limit as 10,000 users per server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up separate buckets and AWS Transfer instances for each vendor is a best practice for workload separation.  I would recommend setting up a custom URL in Route53 for each of your vendors and not attempt to consolidate on a single URL (it isn't natively supported).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/requirements-dns.html

Answer (score 0):

While setting up separate AWS Transfer Family instances will work, it comes at a higher cost (remember you are charged even if you stop until the time you delete, you are billed $0.30 per hour which is ~ $216 per month).
The other way is to create different users (one per vendor) and use different home directories (one per vendor) and lock down permissions through IAM role for that user (also there is provision to use a [scope-down policy](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/faqs/) along with AD). If using service managed users see this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/service-managed-users.html.